# Is there a way to graph the real-time download/upload speed real time during a speed test using the speedtest-cli library for Python?

Tags: python

While I know how to find the end download/upload speed, I'm looking for a way to get data for the download/upload speed real-time **during** the test and plot it onto a graph, kind of how when doing a speed test on Speedtest.net you see a mini graph showing fluctuations during the test.

Comment: I made https://internetspeed.my that offers a graph of the internet speed.  Just plotted the output from python to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data obtained from the speed test library. And pass the data into a graphing library like https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py to show graph. For realtime update just set up an interval and refresh the graph at a fixed interval.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work successfully within minutes (It uses speedtest.net internally). See if it suits your case:

Github: ansemjo/speedtest-plotter: running scheduled speedtests inside docker and plotting the results with gnuplot
https://github.com/ansemjo/speedtest-plotter

Example view of the graph (Gnuplot) you'll get:

[image: Example view1]

[image: Example view2]

Docker command to plot hourly. Adjust the cron and timezone as necessary.

```bash
docker run -d --name SpeedTester -p 8000:8000 -e TZ="Australia/Sydney" -e SCHEDULE="0 * * * *" ghcr.io/ansemjo/speedtest
```

More customisation can be found at https://github.com/ansemjo/speedtest-plotter